# How can i disable the previous dates in html code?

Tags: html, datetime, datepicker

I tried so many ways I found online and nothing works for me. Please help me figure out and thanks alot.

Here is my codes.
Now I just use simple date/calendar because I couldn't find anything else. It works fine but I need the system to not to be able to select previous date.

```
<!-- Date -->
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="date" name="date"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.box-body -->
```

Comment: Can you please post your whole code for better understanding. @Sam

Comment: Hi. This is actually the whole codes for my date attribute. I didnt use any jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use min attribute of the element

```
 <input id='myDate' type="date" name="date" min="2015-10-28"/>
```

```js
 document.getElementById("myDate").min = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" +  parseInt(new Date().getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + new Date().getDate()
```

```html
Date:
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="bday" min="2015-10-28" >


<p><strong>Note:</strong> input elements with type="date" are not supported in Internet Explorer or Firefox.</p>
```

Comment: and how to get the date before (which is 28-10-2015 for today) by default? I mean I dont want to hard code the date.

Comment: and i forgot, Thank you for the answer :D